# custom kernel: bad shim signature

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I upgraded my laptop bios this morning.  Afterwards, only Windows would boot on my dual-boot UEFI system.

I booted a live Ubuntu system from USB and used boot-repair to repair this.  I can now boot Ubuntu again, but only official kernels.  Kernels I've built myself give a "bad shim signature" error.  This was not the case yesterday.

How do I get back to being able to boot custom kernels?

Running Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: For anyone who comes after: turning off secure boot in the BIOS settings fixed this for me.

Comment: you could provide your solution as an actual answer (for the sake of visibility) - it worked for me as well. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, turning off secure boot in the BIOS settings fixed this for me.