# I can't boot into Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, 23.10

I installed Ubuntu 23.10 today, alongside windows and Ubuntu 20.04, which both worked before I installed Ubuntu 23.10. Now I can boot into 23.10 and into Windows, but I cannot boot into Ubuntu 20.04.
I get "ERROR Bad shim signature" when I begin booting after selecting 20.04 in the boot menu.

I have searched Ask Ubuntu and have come up with this unanswered question which seems closely related:
[Bad shim signature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1495766/bad-shim-signature)

Ubuntu displayed boot problems mentioning the bios and GRUB when I tried logging in to 20.04 today. I've discovered that Ubuntu logs boot problems, so I'm looking into that. I'll post my progress. Meanwhile 23.10 works, so I can install programs and link my old data files.

I've run boot-repair and the output is very long. I've edited the question to include the suggested fix. Would it be safe to proceed, or should I add the whole file so that those in-the-know can look at it?
Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
sda12,
using the following options:  sda2/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 23.10 entry (sda2/efi/****/shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI****\shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)

Yesterday, Feb. 21st 2024, I attempted to switch off the secure boot, and swapped the boot os order. I can now boot into Ubuntu 20.04 again - success!
The error messages I get on booting into Ubuntu were still being displayed. So, in the absence of advice from anyone who knows about these things, I took a risk and ran boot-repair, selecting the recommended option. Now I am still getting those same error messages, so boot-repair didn't work for me.
However, the os is now working so this Question can be closed.
Thanks to anyone who offered advice.

Comment: Why -1? What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom kernel: bad shim signature](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420339/custom-kernel-bad-shim-signature)

Comment: It mentions bios, so it may be a connected problem.

Comment: I would try running `boot-repair` utility. See if it recommends changes to your configuration / BIOS.

Comment: Note the `shim` error you researched is **NOT** the same as the duplicate `shim` link nominated for closing your question.

Answer (score 0):

One of the services that run on ubuntu is the `secureboot-db` which runs on both `20.04` and `23.10`. The main aim of this service is to update the DBX or the `Secure Boot Forbidden Signature Database` in the BIOS's secure boot storage. The Forbidden Signature database is in essence a revocation list, about what's not allowed to sign the booting binaries (grub, kernel etc).

The [DBX version available in 23.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/secureboot-db) is a lot more recent than [the one available in 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/secureboot-db), and revokes the older of the 2 sets of certificates used to sign the boot files in `20.04`.

To try and fix this **without turning off secure boot**, I can suggest the following:

- Boot into `23.10`
- Mount the 20.04 boot structure into `/media/oldroot` (20.04 root device(`/`), 20.04 `/boot` if it exists. **/boot/efi too, ONLY IF IT IS NOT SHARED WITH `23.10`**)
- mount `/proc`, `/dev`, `/tmp`, `/run` and `/sys` into their corresponding locations in `/mount/oldroot/` with options `-o bind` i.e. `mount $MOUNT /media/oldroot/$MOUNT -o bind`.
- chroot into `/media/oldroot` and run `apt distupgrade` and `apt install` either `image-generic` or `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` to get the latest available kernels for `20.04`.

Now you should have all the updates required to boot the `20.04` with secure boot enabled.